# boton javascript que permita cambiar el Meta tag de bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, drupal7

Necesito un botón en mi sitio Drupal 7, donde al presionarlo me cambie el content del meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

de bootstrap ubicado en `sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/system/html.tpl.php`, a

```
content="1024"
```

y este botón solo se muestre en móvil.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Buenos días, por favor edita tu pregunta con lo que has desarrollado y probado.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _meta tag de bootstrap a 1024_? Creo que estás confundiendo términos porque eso no tiene sentido.

Comment: Bootstrap en su archivo html.tpl.php tiene el meta: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">, necesito cambiar el valor del content por content="1024" con una función en js para agregarlo a un boton en un sitio

Comment: Eso que dices es un poco raro, si quieres que el botón solo se muestre en ciertas resoluciones tendrás que usar _media queries_

Comment: Mi cliente quiere un boton en el sitio que se muestre solo en movil y que permita cambiar del sitio responsive a como se ve en Desktop, tal cual al boton de chrome "request desktop site" pero dentro del sitio. Se me ocurrió utilizar js para cambiar el meta tag de bootstrap que es el que hace que el sitio se vea responsive. Cualquier otra sugerencia la aceptaré.

Comment: El meta viewport no es de bootstrap y lo que hace es ajustar el ancho y el zoom para adaptarse a ciertos dispositivos pero un diseño responsivo se controla principalmente con _media queries_.

Comment: Tengo el responsive del sitio con media queries, el problema viene que el cliente quiere que cuando el sitio se muestre responsive en el movil exista un boton que le permita cambiar el sitio responsive a como se ve en desktop, es decir, quiere ambos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si esto es más o menos lo que buscas: he hecho un botón que cambia la etiqueta meta pero haciendo referencia a ella con un id, cambia tanto el texto del botón como el atributo meta.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var textoAnterior = "Cambiar Content de la etiqueta meta a 1024";
  var textoNuevo = "Cambiar Content de la etiqueta meta al original";
  var valorAtributoNuevo = "1024";
  var valorAtributoAnterior = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0";

  $("#botonCambiarContent").on("click", function() {

    valorAtributoActual = $("#etiquetaACambiar").attr("content");

    if (valorAtributoActual !== valorAtributoNuevo) {
      $("#etiquetaACambiar").attr("content", valorAtributoNuevo);
      $("#botonCambiarContent").text(textoNuevo);
    } else {
      $("#etiquetaACambiar").attr("content", valorAtributoAnterior);
      $("#botonCambiarContent").text(textoAnterior);
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta id="etiquetaACambiar" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<button id="botonCambiarContent" type="button">Cambiar Content de la etiqueta meta a 1024</button>
```

Comment: Ahora el problema que tengo es que una vez el usuario pulsa el boton y navega en el sitio, este vuelve al responsive, es decir, no se mantiene el sitio en 1024 a lo largo de la navegación. ¿Es esto posible, es decir, que el sitio se mantenga el 1024?